# Unity IL2CPP Error : section name section has wrong type: 2621440

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk

I'm trying to build my game to android 64 bit with Unity 2018.3.3, but IL2CPP crashes ! every thing works fine when I build with Mono but it only give 32 bit apk !
When I build an Empty Project with IL2CPP also it builds successfully. However, when I build my game this error appears !

**Error Log :**

```
Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe --convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARMv7" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="D:\F\UnityProjects\aa\LudoCash2018\LudoCash\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a\libil2cpp.so" --cachedirectory="D:\F\UnityProjects\aa\LudoCash2018\LudoCash\Assets\..\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache" --additional-include-directories="C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\bdwgc/include" --additional-include-directories="C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\libil2cpp/include" --tool-chain-path="D:/Android/NDK/android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r16b" --map-file-parser="C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools\MapFileParser\MapFileParser.exe" --directory="D:\F\UnityProjects\aa\LudoCash2018\LudoCash\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed" --generatedcppdir="D:\F\UnityProjects\aa\LudoCash2018\LudoCash\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput" 

stdout:
Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain
    Output directory: D:\F\UnityProjects\aa\LudoCash2018\LudoCash\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a
    Cache directory: D:\F\UnityProjects\aa\LudoCash2018\LudoCash\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache
ObjectFiles: 662 of which compiled: 232
    Time Compile: 93915 milliseconds Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.cpp
    Time Compile: 59848 milliseconds Il2CppAttributes.cpp
    Time Compile: 32501 milliseconds Il2CppInvokerTable.cpp
    Time Compile: 26226 milliseconds Il2CppTypeDefinitions.cpp
    Time Compile: 25855 milliseconds Bulk_Unity.TextMeshPro_1.cpp
    Time Compile: 24122 milliseconds Bulk_Unity.TextMeshPro_2.cpp
    Time Compile: 23019 milliseconds Bulk_Unity.TextMeshPro_3.cpp
    Time Compile: 22983 milliseconds Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_5.cpp
    Time Compile: 22011 milliseconds Bulk_Photon3Unity3D_0.cpp
    Time Compile: 21726 milliseconds Bulk_Generics_1.cpp
Total compilation time: 593312 milliseconds.
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: D:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++ @"C:\Users\aa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp54F9.tmp" -o "D:\F\UnityProjects\aa\LudoCash2018\LudoCash\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_A000625DB05E1C24B205324CC39B9B63\libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id --sysroot "D:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b\platforms\android-16\arch-arm" -gcc-toolchain "D:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64" -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -L "D:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi-v7a" -lgnustl_static -llog -Xlinker -Map="D:\F\UnityProjects\aa\LudoCash2018\LudoCash\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_A000625DB05E1C24B205324CC39B9B63\libil2cpp.map" -rdynamic -fuse-ld=gold.exe

D:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld.gold.exe: error: D:/F/UnityProjects/aa/LudoCash2018/LudoCash/Library/il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache/libil2cpp/D9592FC93105A56D68E5B5908B4B1440.o: section name section has wrong type: 2621440
D:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld.gold.exe: fatal error: D:/F/UnityProjects/aa/LudoCash2018/LudoCash/Library/il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache/libil2cpp/D9592FC93105A56D68E5B5908B4B1440.o: attempt to map 235802126 bytes at offset 235802126 exceeds size of file; the file may be corrupt
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


   مë§ Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.PostprocessObjectFiles(HashSet`1 objectFiles, CppToolChainContext toolChainContext)
   مë§ Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   مë§ il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   مë§ il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   مë§ il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
stderr:

ں«¢£ëںک نï© êُمںéô¤: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: D:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++ @"C:\Users\aa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp54F9.tmp" -o "D:\F\UnityProjects\aa\LudoCash2018\LudoCash\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_A000625DB05E1C24B205324CC39B9B63\libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id --sysroot "D:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b\platforms\android-16\arch-arm" -gcc-toolchain "D:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64" -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -L "D:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi-v7a" -lgnustl_static -llog -Xlinker -Map="D:\F\UnityProjects\aa\LudoCash2018\LudoCash\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_A000625DB05E1C24B205324CC39B9B63\libil2cpp.map" -rdynamic -fuse-ld=gold.exe

D:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld.gold.exe: error: D:/F/UnityProjects/aa/LudoCash2018/LudoCash/Library/il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache/libil2cpp/D9592FC93105A56D68E5B5908B4B1440.o: section name section has wrong type: 2621440
D:\Android\NDK\android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r16b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld.gold.exe: fatal error: D:/F/UnityProjects/aa/LudoCash2018/LudoCash/Library/il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache/libil2cpp/D9592FC93105A56D68E5B5908B4B1440.o: attempt to map 235802126 bytes at offset 235802126 exceeds size of file; the file may be corrupt
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


   مë§ Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.PostprocessObjectFiles(HashSet`1 objectFiles, CppToolChainContext toolChainContext)
   مë§ Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   مë§ il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   مë§ il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   مë§ il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)

UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log()
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunProgram(Program, String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\BuildUtils.cs:128)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase, Action`1) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\BuildUtils.cs:73)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunIl2CppWithArguments(List`1, Action`1, String) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:368)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp(String, String, String, Boolean) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:349)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:211)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:35)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp:Execute(PostProcessorContext)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner:RunAllTasks(PostProcessorContext)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess(BuildTarget, String, String, String, String, String, String, BuildOptions, RuntimeClassRegistry, BuildReport)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess(BuildPostProcessArgs, BuildProperties&)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess(BuildTargetGroup, BuildTarget, String, String, String, Int32, Int32, BuildOptions, RuntimeClassRegistry, BuildReport) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:286)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck()
UnityEditor.DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:172)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods(Boolean, BuildOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons(IBuildWindowExtension, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, BuildPlatform) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:907)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:807)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:410)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke()
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo)
System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[])
UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke(String, Object) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\HostView.cs:342)
UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke(String) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\HostView.cs:336)
UnityEditor.HostView:OldOnGUI() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\HostView.cs:129)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI(Event, Matrix4x4, Rect, Boolean) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\IMGUIContainer.cs:244)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent(Event, Matrix4x4, Rect) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\IMGUIContainer.cs:438)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent(Event) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\IMGUIContainer.cs:421)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleEvent(EventBase) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\IMGUIContainer.cs:401)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent(EventBase, IPanel) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\EventDispatcher.cs:511)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch(EventBase, IPanel, DispatchMode) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\EventDispatcher.cs:307)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent(EventBase, DispatchMode) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\Panel.cs:176)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch(BaseVisualElementPanel) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\UIElementsUtility.cs:245)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\UIElementsUtility.cs:68)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\IMGUI\GUIUtility.cs:179)

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs Line: 128)

Uploading Crash Report
Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!
  at UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) [0x0011f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\BuildUtils.cs:130 
  at UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) [0x00063] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\BuildUtils.cs:73 
  at UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) [0x0008b] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:368 
  at UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (System.String inputDirectory, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory, System.Boolean platformSupportsManagedDebugging) [0x00272] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:349 
  at UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () [0x000ba] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:211 
  at UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) [0x0001e] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:35 
  at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) [0x00203] in <492d67763d4d482e8616a9848b18ccab>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) [0x00074] in <492d67763d4d482e8616a9848b18ccab>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) [0x00261] in <492d67763d4d482e8616a9848b18ccab>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) [0x00001] in <492d67763d4d482e8616a9848b18ccab>:0 
  at UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) [0x000d9] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:286 
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck()
UnityEditor.DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:172)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods(Boolean, BuildOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons(IBuildWindowExtension, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, BuildPlatform) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:907)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:807)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:410)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke()
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo)
System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[])
UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke(String, Object) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\HostView.cs:342)
UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke(String) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\HostView.cs:336)
UnityEditor.HostView:OldOnGUI() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\HostView.cs:129)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI(Event, Matrix4x4, Rect, Boolean) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\IMGUIContainer.cs:244)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent(Event, Matrix4x4, Rect) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\IMGUIContainer.cs:438)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent(Event) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\IMGUIContainer.cs:421)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleEvent(EventBase) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\IMGUIContainer.cs:401)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent(EventBase, IPanel) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\EventDispatcher.cs:511)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch(EventBase, IPanel, DispatchMode) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\EventDispatcher.cs:307)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent(EventBase, DispatchMode) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\Panel.cs:176)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch(BaseVisualElementPanel) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\UIElementsUtility.cs:245)
UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\UIElements\UIElementsUtility.cs:68)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules\IMGUI\GUIUtility.cs:179)

(Filename: <492d67763d4d482e8616a9848b18ccab> Line: 0)
```

I think the error is : 
`error: D:/F/UnityProjects/aa/LudoCash2018/LudoCash/Library/il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache/libil2cpp/D9592FC93105A56D68E5B5908B4B1440.o: section name section has wrong type: 2621440`
and this :
`fatal error: D:/F/UnityProjects/aa/LudoCash2018/LudoCash/Library/il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache/libil2cpp/D9592FC93105A56D68E5B5908B4B1440.o: attempt to map 235802126 bytes at offset 235802126 exceeds size of file; the file may be corrupt`

but I don't know how to fix it !

Please help !

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it ! in Player Setting -> Other Settings, I checked the **Arm64 ONLY**, un-check ArmV7 & x86 and build as usual ! That's it !

Answer (score 0):

I was just reading about IL2CPP with unity. Does this link help you?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2019

There is a specific section

```
IL2CPP Considerations
When exporting your game to platforms like iOS, Unity will use its IL2CPP engine to
"transpile" IL to C++ code which is then compiled using the native compiler of the target
platform. In this scenario, there are several .NET features which are not supported, such
as parts of Reflection, and usage of the dynamic keyword. While you can control using
these features in your own code, you may run into problems using 3rd party DLLs and SDKs
which were not written with Unity and IL2CPP in mind. For more information on this topic,
 please see the Scripting Restrictions docs on Unity's site.

Additionally, as mentioned in the Json.NET example above, Unity will attempt to strip out
unused code during the IL2CPP export process. While this typically isn't an issue, with
libraries that use Reflection, it can accidentally strip out properties or methods that
will be called at run time that can't be determined at export time. To fix these issues,
add a link.xml file to your project which contains a list of assemblies and namespaces to
not run the stripping process against. For full details, please see Unity's docs on
bytecode stripping.
```

Comment: Actually, I'm using many SDKs : Facebook, PlayFab, Unity IAP , Photon, GoogleAds ..etc but it shouldn't be a problem as I think .. 
do you know what this error means ?  `section name section has wrong type: 2621440`

Comment: Also, I'm using for loops like this :
```
for (int i = 0; i < photoBtns.Length; i++)
{
      // set photo id
      photoBtns[i].photo_ID = i;
      // add to dictionary
      PhotoBtnsDic.Add(i, photoBtns[i]);
      //set photo
      photoBtns[i].photo.sprite = LocalPhotos[i];

      **// set onClick
      int index = i;
      photoBtns[i].GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
      {
           selectedPhotoBtn.Selected = false;
           selectedPhotoBtn = photoBtns[index];
           selectedPhotoBtn.Selected = true;
      });
}
``` 
could it be the probem ?

Comment: I'd say a type called "2621440" is a very poor choice of naming. It might be something that is getting purposely obfuscated. It could be that one of the SDK's isn't being translated properly. It could be using a feature that isn't supported. As far as your code... it looks ok, I think. I'm not really an expert in that.

Comment: thanks a lot ! I get around it ! I'll post the solution down there so anyone may make use of it ! I hope you a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the [ProjectName]/Library/il2cpp* folders and then try again and it should work.